# Как ограничить минуты максимальным значением 60? В методы string.format()

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        int hours = (int)(mTimeLeftInMillis / 3600000);
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes,seconds);
        remainingTime.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
```

У меня сейчас минуты могут выходить за значение 60. Мне нужно чтобы минуты не выходили за значение 60, то есть сделать значение 60 максимальной. Скажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: `int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60 % 60;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (minutes > 60){
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    }
```